# How to specify column list in hive insert into query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have just installed and configured Apache Hive version 1.1.0. Then I have created a table by quering this query:

```
create table person (name1 string, surname1 string);
```

And then I want to add one row by:

```
insert into person (name1, surname1) values ("Alan", "Green");
```

And it cause an error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line
>   1:20 cannot recognize input near '(' 'name1' ',' in statement
>   (state=42000,code=40000).

But when I execute query without column list it works fine:

```
insert into person values ("Alan", "Green");
```

The question is: how to specify column list in hiveQL to make insert into?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to this bug [HIVE-9481](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9481), you can specify column list in INSERT statement, since 1.2.0. The syntax is like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...) 
[(column_list)]
[IF NOT EXISTS]] select_statement1 FROM from_statement;
```

example:

```
CREATE TABLE pageviews (userid VARCHAR(64), link STRING, "from" STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (datestamp STRING) 
CLUSTERED BY (userid) INTO 256 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC;

INSERT INTO TABLE pageviews 
PARTITION (datestamp = '2014-09-23')
(userid,link) 
VALUES ('jsmith', 'mail.com');
```

I tested this with Hive 2.1. It works only with INSERT INTO, not with INSERT **OVERWRITE**

And I don't know why this syntax is not mentioned in the Apache wiki page [LanguageManual DML](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9481

Answer (score 4):

Insert into specific columns in the above query:

```
insert into table person (name1, surname1) values ("Alan", "Green");
```

is supported in Hive 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Hive currently not supports such functionality, details [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL)

You must provide full values list.

Comment: Is this still true for Hive version 1.2.1 ??

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support row level inserts,updates and deletes.

However, after creating a table you can have all your data in a file and load the file into hive table. that way you can insert data into a hive table.
You can refer the hive manual for the commands.

There are workarounds for performing inserts/updates and deletes in hive. But its not recommended.